# refresh image on upload

Tags: php

I have a script which uploads an image to the server under the id of the user. To change teh picture the first gets overwritten. The problem is that the old picture, with the dimensions of the new one, shows for a while until they refresh their browser. How can I prevent this from happening?

Script:

```
function uploadProfilePicture($memberID,$extension)
{
    ##### FIND ERRORS #####
    $error = "";

    // check if larger than 5mb
    $avatar = $_FILES['uploadedAvatar'];
    if( $avatar["size"] > 5000000 ){ //5mb
        $error = SETTINGSphoto_less_5meg;
    }
    //check if member selected a photo
    if( $avatar['name'] == "" ){
        $error = SETTINGSphoto_no_upload;
    }

    //check if photo is of allowed formats
    if(  $avatar["type"] != "image/png"  ){
      if(  $avatar["type"] != "image/gif"  ){
        if(  $avatar["type"] != "image/jpg"  ){
            if(  $avatar["type"] != "image/jpeg"  ){
                if(  $avatar["type"] != "image/pjpeg"  ){
                    $error = SETTINGSphoto_file_type;   
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }

    #### END FIND ERRORS #####      

    ##### DISPLAYS ERRORS ######
    if( $error != ""){
            echo '<span style="background-color:#E05641;" class="pint2">'.$error.'</span>';
    ##### END DISPLAYS ERRORS ######


    ##### PROCESS THUMBNAIL AND UPLOAD PICTURE #####
    }else{



        $ext = substr($avatar["name"], -4); //take off extention. 
        $fileName = $memberID.$extension.$ext; // rename picture with member's ID.w
        unlink("photos/".$memberID.$extension.".jpg");
        unlink("photos/".$memberID.$extension."Thumb.jpg");

        copy($avatar['tmp_name'], "photos/".$fileName); //upload temp

        //create virual image
        if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/',strtolower($avatar["name"]))) {  
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("photos/".$fileName);  
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', strtolower($avatar["name"]))) {  
            $im = imagecreatefromgif("photos/".$fileName);  
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', strtolower($avatar["name"]))) {  
            $im = imagecreatefrompng("photos/".$fileName);  
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](jpeg)$/',strtolower($avatar["name"]))) {  
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("photos/".$fileName); 
        }else{
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("photos/".$fileName); 
        }

        //get height and width
        $ox = imagesx($im);  $oy = imagesy($im);  

        $final_width_of_image = 200;
        $final_height_of_image = 200;
        //$ratio = $final_width_of_image / $ox; //find ratio to apply to height
        //$nx = $final_width_of_image; $ny = $oy * $ratio; 
        if( $ox < $oy ){

                $nx = 200; 
                $ny = floor($oy * (200 / $ox)); 

        }else{

                $ny = 200; 
                $nx = floor($ox * (200 / $oy)); 

        }


        //$nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);   
        //imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);    //create new pic    
        $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);   
        imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);  

        unlink("photos/".$fileName); //delete temp image

        imagejpeg($nm, "photos/".$memberID.$extension.".jpg",100); //save image // 100 = quality 

        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("photos/".$memberID.$extension.".jpg");  
        $nm = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
        imagecopyresampled($nm, $im,0,0,0,0,200,200,200,200);
        imagejpeg($nm, "photos/".$memberID.$extension."Thumb.jpg",100);



        $sql = "UPDATE exchange SET photo = 1 WHERE id = '$memberID'"; //update db
        $mysql = new mysql();
        $mysql->query($sql);
        ##### END PROCESS THUMBNAIL AND UPLOAD PICTURE ##### 

        echo '<span class="pint2">'.SETTINGSphoto_chage_success.' <a style="color:#ffffff" href="'.$_ENV['rootURL'].'/'.( in_array($_GET['lang'],$_ENV['supportedLanguages']) ? $_GET['lang']."/" : $nothing).HEADlanguage_exchange.'/id/'.$memberID.'">'.SETTINGSphoto_view_profile.'</a></span>';
        }
}
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with the browser cache, and I don't really know a way around it, but for checking the uploaded image type, please just put them in an array and use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: how can i put them in an array?

Comment: I don't think I've seen a nested if statement that deep in a long time. Kudos.

Comment: `$image_types = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', ...); if(!in_array($avatar['type'], $image_types)){...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that the old picture, with the dimensions of the new one, shows for a while until they refresh their browser. How can I prevent this from happening?

You can solve this by telling the user she should clear the browser cache.

If that is not an option, you want to actually prevent the user to cache the image.

So you need to make a difference between each revision of the image. Add a integer field to your database you store the revision number of the image. Then each time you output the user's image, fetch the actual revision number from the database as well. Add it as the query-info-part of the image URL:

```
<img src="avatars/user/929292/photo.jpg?revision">
                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

The browser will still cache profile pictures but you make him aware of the revision, so a specific revision is cached.

Old avatar picture:

```
<img src="avatars/user/929292/photo.jpg?1">
```

Then the user uploads a new image, you increment the revision field, the new avatar image is:

```
<img src="avatars/user/929292/photo.jpg?2">
```

If the revision changes, the browser notices that and will pick the image from the server.

Comment: genius! thanks Now I understand why people put the time() at the end of css files in the php with a ? before

Comment: If you take the time it has the problem that it won't get cached, so the site becomes slowlier. You actually want the revision, same for CSS. You can as well MD5 the file-contents if you don't want to use the mysql database for this, but that can become computing intensive.

Comment: in the revision field, can i just put the date it was changed?

Comment: you could do as well (like a MYSQL timestamp), however a simple integer is not using that much space.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the new image a slightly different filename, so the browser loads the new  image rather than using the old cached one.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code for the image source you can append a timestamp to force the photo to always appear as a new photo. Throw some logic in to only do this for updated records and you'll be more cache friendly.

```
<img src="your_profile_url.jpg?<?= time(); ?>"/>
```